# The Bars of my Histogram are not showing and are cut off

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I wrote down [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOvgu.png) code, the program runs perfectly without any errors, but the bars of the histogram are cut off at 1.0 on the y axis. Why is this happening? Thanks for the help!

My Code:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
plt.hist(list1, bins=10, rwidth=0.9)
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.show()
```

Edit:
Ok, I am giving it 10 for bins. But if I change the value of bins to let's say...

```
plt.hist(list1, bins=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

I get this

[image: this].

Now what?

NOTE: I want to use plt.hist to make a histogram, I don't want to use plt.bar to make a bar.

Comment: Could you edit your question so we can copy and paste your code?

Comment: That is what you've told it to do. Do you want `plt.bar` instead?

Comment: What were you expecting? You've a variable `bins` that you don't use.

Comment: @burntchowmein I have edited my post so that you can get the code too.

tomjn No, I am making a histogram, not a bar.

Comment: with 10 bins and a list of 10 items 1 to 10 you get exactly one item per bin, so all histogram bars will have a height of 1, so everything is OK, nothing is cut off

Comment: @WaliullahBukhari my question is what do you want the plot to show? What you have is the correct result, you are histograming your data and have one entry per bin except the final bin. What values of y do you want in your plot?

Answer (score 0):

A histogram, which is what you are plotting, shows the distribution of measurements you place as an argument in `plt.hist()`. Since your inputs are numbers that don't repeat, the distribution is uniform and therefore all the heights are the same. You may be getting the impression the bars are getting cut. But calling `plt.gca().set(ylim = (0, 10))` will show you that all the bars are simply the same height. A histogram might not be what you are looking for, but rather, a bar plot. If that is the case, read this:
https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html

Answer (score 0):

## Solution: you should use `plt.bar` instead of `plt.hist`

```py
x = [xlabel for xlabel in range(len(list1))]
plt.bar(x, list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you pass `width` to `plt.hist`:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
plt.hist(list1, bins=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], width=0.9)
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]